# Why I am getting %E2%80%8B in my URL during unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, urlencode

I am writing the unit testing for my controller and am getting 404 instead of 200 success.
When I search on the console it is showing we WARN log like

```
WARN  [2021-02-12T11:53:27.711+0530] servlet.PageNotFound ||${fallback:user}|No mapping for GET /person%E2%80%8B/contacts%E2%80%8B/details
```

Why mapping changed to `/person%E2%80%8B/contacts%E2%80%8B/details` instead of `/person/contacts/details`

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
public class PersonControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonController personController;

    @Mock
    private PersonService personService;

    @Before
    public void setupMethod() {

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(personController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getPersonContactDetailTest() throws Exception {
    
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("Test");

        Mockito.when(personService.getPersonContactDetail()).thenReturn(person);

        RequestBuilder rqBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/person/contacts/details")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        mockMvc.perform(rqBuilder).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());

        Mockito.verify(personService, times(1)).getPersonContactDetail());
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be URL string encoding. Use the URL decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%E2%80%8B` is the code for a "ZERO-WIDTH SPACE" character.

It has probably been inserted without you noticing it somehow. I recommend completely removing the string where the URL is defined and re-write it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked I have typed my URL again.